# Change in ApplicationInsights>TelemetryChannel>StorageFolder does not reflects

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have permission issues with the default storage folder on Windows Server 2016, I keep getting the following error on TRACE:

```
AI (Internal): [Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-WindowsServer-TelemetryChannel] Unauthorized access dequeuing file, folder not accessible: 5dd29ef58369a24b5a015ae5d7a400adffee3c3f379057066bda9dd1ad8a4771. Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\5dd29ef58369a24b5a015ae5d7a400adffee3c3f379057066bda9dd1ad8a4771' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.PlatformFolder.GetFiles() in E:\A\_work\13\s\BASE\src\ServerTelemetryChannel\Implementation\PlatformFolder.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.TransmissionStorage.GetTransmissionFiles() in E:\A\_work\13\s\BASE\src\ServerTelemetryChannel\Implementation\TransmissionStorage.cs:line 257
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.TransmissionStorage.LoadFilesOrderedByDateFromFolder() in E:\A\_work\13\s\BASE\src\ServerTelemetryChannel\Implementation\TransmissionStorage.cs:line 284
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.TransmissionStorage.GetOldestTransmissionFileOrNull() in E:\A\_work\13\s\BASE\src\ServerTelemetryChannel\Implementation\TransmissionStorage.cs:line 268
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.TransmissionStorage.Dequeue() in E:\A\_work\13\s\BASE\src\ServerTelemetryChannel\Implementation\TransmissionStorage.cs:line 134.
```

I have tried adding the following change to `ApplicationInsights.config` by refering [to documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/telemetry-channels#configuration-by-using-applicationinsightsconfig-for-aspnet-applications) :

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
                <StorageFolder>D:\ApplicationInsights\My.App.API\Prod</StorageFolder>
</TelemetryChannel>
```

but this does not takes any effect. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what's kind of your app? asp.net web project? and can you please share us the code that how do you use TelemetryChannel?

Comment: Its ASP.NET Web API 2.2. I configured it through the VS2019 wizard and it added ApplicationInsights.config to my project then I added the iKey and everything apart from this issue started working.

Comment: For the TEMP folder, have you tried set it's permission to Full control for everyone?

Comment: Just tried giving Full Control to Everyone, but still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission issue on the custom folder I had created. I came to this realisation after reporting an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2000#issuecomment-679843660)